# asp.net webconfig https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, rule

I want to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com in webconfig. I'm using the following code for this operation. but does't work.

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule redirects any incoming request to www.domain.com to domain.com while preserving the HTTP(S) protocol:

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

**[Reference](http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain)**